# Relation of bound charges and polarization

Tags: charge, maxwell-equations, dipole-moment

In this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density#Other_expressions) the polarization
$$
  \vec P = \rho_\mathrm{b} \vec d
$$
is determined from the density of bound charges $\rho_\mathrm{b}$ and the displacement vector $\vec d$, which denotes the displacement of positive and negative charges in a small volume. If I recall correctly, the volume as a whole has neutral charge.

Now if I am not mistaken, the relation $\rho_\mathrm{b} = - \nabla \vec P$ should hold as well. But how can one verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine some volume filled with point-like charges at the location $\mathbf{R}$, the charge density is then
$$\rho = \sum_{n=1}^N q_n \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_n - \mathbf{R}) $$
where $\mathbf{r}_n$ is the vector that shows from the centre of the volume to the nth charge. The macroscopic charge density however is an average over this microscopic charge density, so $\rho_m = \langle \rho \rangle$. To average the microscopic charge density use some smearing function $g(\mathbf{r})$ and take the convolution with $\rho$ to get the averaged charge density at the location $\mathbf{r}$
\begin{align*}
\langle \rho\rangle (\mathbf{r}) &= \int \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime}\, g(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}) \sum_{n=1}^{N}q_n \delta(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}_n - \mathbf{R}) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N} q_n \int \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime}\, g(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}) \delta(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}_n -\mathbf{R})
\end{align*}
If you now taylor expand the integrand, assuming that $\mathbf{r}<<\mathbf{R}$ you get the following terms
\begin{align*}
\langle \rho \rangle (\mathbf{r}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} q_n \int \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime}\, g(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}) \delta(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{R}) \\
& + \sum_{n=1}^{N} q_n \int \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime} g(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}) \Big(-\mathbf{r}_n \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{r}^{\prime}} \delta(\mathbf{r}^{\prime} - \mathbf{R}) \Big)
\end{align*}
Now the first term gives you a sum over the smeared out charges, which is simply 0 if the Volume has no net charge. The second term however can be further simplified with integration by parts
\begin{align*}
&\quad\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}q_n \mathbf{r}_n \cdot \int \mathrm{d}^3r^{\prime} \delta(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{R}) \nabla_{\mathbf{r}^{\prime}} g(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{N}q_n \mathbf{r}_n \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{R}}\,g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}) \\
&= \mathbf{d} \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf{R}}\, g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r})
\end{align*}
Where $\mathbf{d}$ is the microscopic dipole moment. We can now change the variables and get that the averaged bound charge density can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
\langle\rho\rangle(\mathbf{r}) &= -\mathbf{d} \cdot \nabla_{r}\, g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}) \\
&= - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{d}\, g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r})
\end{align*}
This smeared out dipole vector is the polarisation $\mathbf{P}$, so we get that $\langle \rho \rangle = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$. And recalling that $\mathbf{d} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} q_n \mathbf{r}_n$, so the polarisation can be written as
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} q_n \mathbf{r}_n g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}) 
\end{align*}
For simplicity let's look at two charges with opposite sign now so then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) &= \Big( q \mathbf{r}_1 - q \mathbf{r}_2 \Big) g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}) \\
&= q \mathbf{D} g(\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}) 
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{D}$ is the displacement vector. Now for the units to work out $g$ has to have units of $1 / V$ so $q g$ is charge per Volume which is the charge density so $\mathbf{P} = \rho \mathbf{D}$

Comment: Your notation is not clear. What is  $\bf r$ in your first formula?

Comment: sorry I got a bit lazy sometimes, the LHS should be $\rho(\mathbf{r})$, so $\mathbf{r}$ is the general point where we're looking at the charge density

Comment: Ok, but then it seems to me that there is some redundancy between $\bf R$ and ${\bf r}_n$. Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but then you'd have to change the taylor expansion somehow. This way it's also more convenient if you want to sum over multiple volumes that each contain some charges, like say you were summing over different molecules each with their own protons and electrons.

Comment: You have many formulas with a function fo ${\bf r}$ on the left-hand side and a function of ${\bf r}$  and ${\bf R}$  on the right-hand side of the equations. If you want to provide a useful answer you cannot skip on mathematical consistency.

Comment: Well in my defense, the LHS is always a function of $\mathbf{r}$ and I did say that $\mathbf{R}$ is the location/center of the molecule/charged Volume.

Comment: @Wihtedeka Thank you for your answer. Did you find a similar derivation in related literature? I would be thankful for any references to text books, lecture notes, or similar.

Comment: I don't know if there's any literature for this derivation, it's taken from my own lectures notes from my electrodynamics class and those are in german, I suppose I could upload those somewhere if you want.

Comment: @Wihtedeka Wow, that would be great.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AY2_uldCaAfq2KblbOOxTvxv9BwBdOyE/view?usp=sharing